# How to respond an error in a Parse Cloud Function and prevent retries?

Tags: parse-platform

Parse clients automatically retries network calls because of, you know, network.

I have a Parse Cloud Function that may return an error.
In that case I don't want the client to retry the call, because it'll fail again and again until the client stop trying.

Is there any way I can prevent the retry if the function was properly handled and an error was sent?

If there's no way, how bad it is to send a success with an error flag?

Answer (score 1):

Clients will retry only if the error is due to network connectivity or server availability issues. If the error is any other type of error, as could happen when a Cloud function returns an error, or a save is rejected, the client will not retry. In general it does not make sense to retry here because retrying will rarely result in a successful response when the error is not connectivity/server related.

Comment: I know it's a long time, but I just tried and the unexpected behaviour is still happening. My function sends an http request and if it receives an error it respond an error to the client, then the client retry the exaclty same request, that will lead to another error and retry ...

Answer (score 1):

You may use [error codes](https://www.parse.com/docs/android/guide#errors) better on client to stop retries. This include network error code as well.

Comment: Aren't the retries made whithout the client being told that any error occured?

Answer (score 0):

I used this to disable retry on Cloud run function when 5XX error occurs, did this in my parse configuration file after initialize it :

```
Parse.CoreManager.set("REQUEST_ATTEMPT_LIMIT", 1);
```

but you can check the source code if you want to disable retry on another function if I misunderstood which function you meant